# How to bind @Input decorator property in html template

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to create a simple Angular component named LabelComponent with label-component for selector.

It should display a  with class label.
It takes two inputs, a text label to display and a text color color.

```
// Angular 8.x code
import { Component, Input, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

 
@Component({
  selector:'label-component',
  template: `
    <div [ngClass]="label" style="color: {{color}};">Hello World!</div>
  `
})
export class LabelComponent {
@Input() label: string;
@Input() color: string;
 
}

// #region Preview
@Component({
    template: `<label-component label='Hello World!' color='red'></label-component>`
})
```

I git this error :

> typeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nativeElement')

Comment: Why is ngClass your label..?

Comment: This code works fine, except it looks like you're confusing `label` and `class`: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eygpa7?file=src/app/label/label.component.html Maybe you should check what line that error is pointing to?

Comment: This typeError could be from somewhere else in your code. The code looks fine. Just remove that [ngClass], and use style binding for the color eg. [style.color]="color".